# android change selected tab background color

Tags: java, android

I came from objective-c and I am an Android newbie. I am using following method that intends to change tabColor for index 0. But I would like to change default grey tab when selected. Thank you.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Comment: Are you trying to change it when it is selected, and then switch it back when it becomes unselected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener l) on the TabHost:

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    int tab = myTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
  }
});
```

Maybe there is a simpler way, i dont have use it before ;)

Comment: now, still having same background default color until tab is pressed. Then, remains always cyan. I set a switch case to control which one is pressed in order to go back to default color and works but when app starts, still grey and first click is yellow default when pressed :(

Comment: for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++), implemented onTabChanged() solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Android allows for a StateList drawable xml file that is the intended way to get the effect you are after.

[read about it here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

The idea is you make an xml file that declares a different drawable (or color if you want plain colors) for each state. Then when you are apply that statelist drawable as the background of your View, and it will handle the "magic" of switching your view image for you so that you don't have to worry about doing it manually from java code.

so your code snippet would look something like this:

```
myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_state_list_filename);
```

Here is an example of a state list file that I've used on a button. You can copy this into an xml file in your drawables folder, then modify it to use whichever states and images you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/darkblue1" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/darkblue1" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/lightblue1" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

I think (but am not certain) that to use colors instead of drawables you'd just change `"@drawable/blahblah"` to `"#FF121212"` where the first two digits are alpha, and the next 6 are hex value for the color you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, android:color = #"F121212". But xml has static content, I need to set it in the activity

Comment: I've never done it before, but you should be able to instantiate it dynamically also. See the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the markup of the TabHost

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one to solve my problem:

```
    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```